# Do Members of Parliament have to register interests before voting?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, procedure

Are Lords and Members of Parliament obliged to register an interest prior to voting on proposed UK legislation?

Comment: Isn't vested interests the point of the House of Lords?

Comment: We all have a vested interest in remaining in the EU and/or the Single Market free from tariffs and trade barriers.  This question insinuates that a Lord is not voting per their conscience but for a nefarious attempt to profit.   The same accusation could be levelled in reverse for anyone voting FOR Brexit regarding business interests.  This question is worded with bias and does not require any reference to the EU or Brexit to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They have a **[Register of Lords' Interests](https://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/standards-and-interests/register-of-lords-interests/?letter=H)** similar to the Commons "Register of Members' Interests".

It is published on line and you can go to the link I've provided to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [register of members' interests](https://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/standards-and-financial-interests/parliamentary-commissioner-for-standards/registers-of-interests/register-of-members-financial-interests/), and MPs are supposed to say in debates if they have relevant financial interests - but the requirements are weak, and the punishment for breaking them is a slap on the wrist.

For example, if a foreign billionaire hires an MP's partner for a six-figure salary, that's not a reportable financial interest. And if it's discovered an MP "forgot" to declare a reportable interest? They might be asked to... apologise.